# Refresh image after JSlider is used to change image

Tags: java, swing, opencv, image-processing

I have a program which will change threshold in a img but i do not know how to refresh image. It will create two JFrame windows one for slider and one for image. I do get value from a slider to go to threshold. But how do I Refresh changed image. Sorry for posting whole code but I can't figure this out.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import  java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfDouble;

public class Draw extends JFrame{

    JSlider slider;
    JLabel label;
    JLabel test1;
    int Actual;
    int value = 100;
    public Draw(){

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 100);
        add(slider);

        label = new JLabel();
        add(label);

        test1 = new JLabel();
        add(test1);

        event e = new event();
        slider.addChangeListener(e);





    }
     public class event implements ChangeListener {

         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
              value = slider.getValue();
              label.setText("Current Value " + value);



         }
     }


     public static void main(String agrs[]){

         System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
         Draw sl = new Draw();
         sl.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         sl.setSize(300,100);
         sl.setVisible(true);
         sl.setTitle("Slider Bar");
         sl.converter();
         sl.repaint();
         sl.revalidate();


     }

 public void converter(){


         Mat imageInMat = Imgcodecs.imread("C:/Users/ja/workspace/imgtomath/bin/imgtomath/bowl.jpg",0);
         if(imageInMat.empty()== true)
             {System.out.println("Error no image found!!");}
         else
             System.out.println("Image loaded");


         Mat thresh = new Mat();
        Imgproc.threshold(imageInMat, thresh, value, 250, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

        BufferedImage bufImage = Mat2BufferedImage(thresh); 
        displayImage(bufImage); 
        }

 public BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat m){
        //source: http://answers.opencv.org/question/10344/opencv-java-load-image-to-gui/
        //Fastest code
        //The output can be assigned either to a BufferedImage or to an Image

         int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
         if ( m.channels() > 1 ) {
             type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
         }
         int bufferSize = m.channels()*m.cols()*m.rows();
         byte [] b = new byte[bufferSize];
         m.get(0,0,b); // get all the pixels
         BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(m.cols(),m.rows(), type);
         final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
         System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);  
         return image;
        }

 public void displayImage(Image img2)
    {   
    //BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File("/HelloOpenCV/lena.png"));
    ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img2);
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();

    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  

    frame.setSize(img2.getWidth(null)+50, img2.getHeight(null)+50);     

    JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
    lbl.setIcon(icon);  
    frame.add(lbl);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that the problem is that if you call `converter()` from `stateChanged()`, it will create a new JFrame every time you change the value on the slider?

Here's a simple proposal to prevent that:

`stateChanged`:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
  value = slider.getValue();
  label.setText("Current Value " + value);
  converter();
}
```

`displayImage`:

```
 private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image JFrame");
 JLabel lbl = null;

 public void displayImage(Image img2){   

    if(lbl==null){
       lbl = new JLabel();

       frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());    
       frame.setSize(img2.getWidth(null)+50, img2.getHeight(null)+50);     

       frame.add(lbl);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img2);
    lbl.setIcon(icon);  

}
```

Also: You should create your Swing components on the Event thread from your main method, as described in: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html